# OWIN based In-process HTTP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I have [OWIN enabled Web API 2 Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) and I want to host it in .NET Console App and the only client for that service would also be in the same application's process. So, it should not be possible to access the service's endpoint by any other process. Is this possible?

If I run my app like this:

```
using (WebApp.Start<MyStartup>(new StartOptions(MyUrl) { ServerFactory = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" }))
{
   StartClientThread();

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

it then will be accessible to any client on the hosting machine but I need to limit the clients to that same process only.

This is possible without OWIN so the requests are sent by using HTTP stack inproc:

```
HttpServer server = InitHttpServer();

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(server, false))
{
   // use client's methods to send http requests to the service.
}
```

But I need similar with OWIN.

Comment: Why use HTTP at all if it's all in process?

Comment: I have a single Web API Service implementation, based on a consuming client it can be consumed in-proc as well as a regular Web Service hosted in IIS. The point here is to reuse as much code as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.Owin.Testing` nuget package. This is mainly for testing but I think is this case it will serve your purpose.

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
{
    var result = await server.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/book");
    string responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseContent);
}
```

As you can see, you can use `server.HttpClient` to send request to your app.

I just don't know if it's good in performance as selfhost is.

Comment: Looks promising, thank you. Do you know if the library has any limitations, like for instance, poor performance, to be used in production system?